# Can an Iraqi citizen, with a Turkish short-term residence permit, apply for a German visa in Turkey?

Tags: visas, turkey, schengen-visas, iraqi-citizens

Can an Iraqi citizen, with a Turkish short-term residence permit, apply for a German visa in Turkey?

Usually, we need to apply from Jordan. But we often get refused to enter Jordan, therefore making the German visa very difficult to apply for.

Comment: What does a Turkish short-term permit cover? If you can live there for several months, the answer is probably yes. If you live there for a few weeks, the answer is probably no.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify questions / comments. Putting on hold.